# Preact: child component with state as prop does not rerender on state change if in array of components

Tags: state, preact

If **currentQuestion** in the state of the parent Component gets updated it rerenders the parent component perfectly fine with the new state.

The problem is, that the child component rendered from the view array seems to not get the updated state which is passed as a prop and so it does not rerender.

If i move render the Child component directly in the render function of the parent (not from an array) everything works as expected.

I dont find the problem here, would be awesome if someone could help.

**Parent**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentQuestion: 0
    };

   // Child components should be stored in an array
   this.views = [
     <Questions
       currentQuestion={this.state.currentQuestion}
     />
   ];
 }

 render() {
   return <div className={style.quiz}>
     // Clicking this button, the parent gets rerendered properly with new state
     <button onClick={() => this.setState({currentQuestion: 3})}>Test</button>
     <div className={style.views}>
       {this.views.map(view => view)}
     </div>
   </div>;
 }
```

}

**Child**

```
class Questions extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    // If the state of the parent component gets updated (button click), the props in here should update and therefore this should be called, which is not the case
    return <div>
      {this.props.currentQuestion}
    </div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The child components are not being updated when the parent component is updated because the child components are instantiated only when the parent's constructor is run.

A way to solve this is to make sure the child components are also updated every time the parent updates (when this.setState({ currentQuestion:  }) is called).

```
render() {
    return <div className={style.quiz}>
        ...
         <Questions currentQuestion={this.state.currentQuestion} />
        ...
     </div>;
}
```